# Which Built-in account to run SQL Express 08

Tags: sql-server

I've just installed SQL Express 08 R2 using default choices. I notice that the 'Log on as:' property is 'Network Service'.  Is that correct?

fwiw, This instance lives only to serve IIS (runs on the same box) and only needs to respond to remote admin access via our VPN.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your web app(s) need SQL Server to do on their behalf.  If all you're app is doing is reading and writing data in a local database then you'll be fine with that.